# Attach WinDbg to a process run from HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run at login?

Tags: c#, windows-xp, windbg

I have a .NET application deployed across 28,000 workstations currently. On all of them, that process is launched at user login from the `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run` registry key. On *most* of those workstations, it works fine, but on a few, it crashes when running in this way. Annoyingly, launching it manually after login works fine, and no crash happens.

So I'm trying to work out how to get [`WinDbg`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WinDbg) up and running and attached to this process in time for me to try to get a memory dump and at least some idea of what's going on.

How can I do that? As far as I'm aware, the order of automatic start-up of applications is not guaranteed on Windows (It's WindowsXP SP3, in case that matters), and so this isn't going to be super easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the ways to do it is [GFlags](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc738435%28WS.10%29.aspx). Gflags can be instructed to attach to the debugger when the process launches.

And debugger script can be passed in the command line to get a memory dump when the process terminates or throws an exception.

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve this would be to deploy a custom build of your application on the workstation that exhibits the problem. That build should call [Debugger.Break()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debugger.break.aspx) as soon as possible in order to trigger the default JIT debugger.

If you [set the necessary registry keys](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/debug/windbg_part1.aspx#_Toc64133667) so that WinDbg is registered as the default JIT debugger, it should attach to your application when it starts, allowing you to get a memory dump.

Comment: Nice idea, but it's a vendor (i.e. Microsoft!) supplied application, so I don't have the code. They want me to supply the memory dump to their support people.